# Free hand image cropping in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm new to image processing. I want to know how to do Free hand Image Cropping in C# windows form application? 
First I want draw the boundary of the object in an image and then the object should be cropped according to the drawn boundary.
What are the ways of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: The basics are easy; just cut the image starting from x-start,y-start to x-end,y-end and copy it into a new image... For the specifics we need more details about your application; what libraries are you using? what format is the image in? how are you storing/accessing the image-data?

Comment: Does "free hand" mean that the cropping region might be non-rectangular, or will it always be a rectangle?

Comment: @Vix yes, that what i meant! cropping region should be non rectangular area!Thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: @Kolky i used system.drawing to draw the image on the windows form.. i want crop the image in non rectangular manner..! Thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `X` and `Y` of your cropping region on `MouseDown` and `Right` and `Bottom` on `MouseUp` events of the control showing your image, and you'll have the cropping region coordinates.

Finally resize the image like this:

```
var cropedImage = yourImage.Clone(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), yourImage.PixelFormat);
```

Comment: I think that with "free hand" the OP means that the cropping area may be non-rectangular.

Comment: @Vilx- Maybe. That wasn't clear to me, anyway in this case he would store a set of points; start on `MouseDown` and capture the points in `MouseMove` event and stop on `MouseUp`. Final result would be a rectangular area for crop which it's `x1` and `y1` is the point captured with minimum (x, y) and it's `x2` and `y2` is the point with maximum (x, y). If the crop area is not rectangular he would create a `TextureBrush` and fill it with the image.

Comment: You could add your coordinates to Point[] on MouseMove. On MouseUp you can create GraphicPath use its AddPolygon method then call CloseFugure ,then call GetBounds. Use that rectangle that you get from get bounds to crop the rectangular image , then fill the outline of GraphicPath with white and draw it on cropped image. Can't test now but theoretically should have same effect as Paint's free hand crop.

Comment: @fardjad  Thanks, but i need what Vilx mentioned! :)

Comment: @user629926 thanks! i got what you said! i will try it out! if you don't mind, if you found a sample code for that, please give me the link! i want to get experience in image processing cause i'm new to it and fond of doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Images are rectangular by definition, so even if you "crop a non-rectangular area", the result will be still a rectangular image.  Try this:

- After you've drawn the crop outline, you'll need to calculate the *region of interest* (ROI) for the crop.  The ROI is just a rectangle that's large enough to cover the entire crop outline (the four points of this ROI are easily calculated).
- Then, you'll need to create a *mask* for this ROI.  This mask will be 1 inside the outline (the part you want to crop) and 0 outside the outline (the part you don't want to crop).  The size of the mask will be the same as the ROI.
- Crop the ROI from the original image ("regular" rectangular cropping)
- Multiply the crop result by the mask.

Answer (score 0):

I have made code for cropping images. simply we need two picture box. one for original image and the second for cropped image. Then see the below codes. these codes you have to write down in the event handler section.

```
int cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight;
        //here rectangle border pen color=red and size=2;
        Pen borderpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        System.Drawing.Image _orgImage;
        Bitmap crop;

        //fill the rectangle color =white
        SolidBrush rectbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White));

 private void pic_scan_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)//here i have use mouse click left button only
                {
                    pic_scan.Refresh();
                    cropX = e.X;
                    cropY = e.Y;
                    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
                }
                pic_scan.Refresh();
            }
            catch { }
        }
 private void pic_scan_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pic_scan.Image == null)
                    return;

                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)//here i have use mouse click left button only
                {
                    pic_scan.Refresh();
                    cropWidth = e.X - cropX;
                    cropHeight = e.Y - cropY;
                }
                pic_scan.Refresh();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void pic_scan_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                if (cropWidth < 1)
                {
                    return;
                }
                System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
                Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(pic_scan.Image, pic_scan.Width, pic_scan.Height);
                crop = new Bitmap(cropWidth, cropHeight);
                Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(crop);
                gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;//here add  System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace;
                gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;//here add  System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace;
                gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;//here add  System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace;
                gfx.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void pic_scan_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
            Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
            gfx.DrawRectangle(borderpen, rect);
            gfx.FillRectangle(rectbrush, rect);
        }
```

It works. try it and enjoy the free coding.